# Error 24 (Too many open files) - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I recently implemented sounds into my game. Every time the user touches the screen, an arrow is shot, and a sound is played. I am using the following code to play the sound:

```
- (void)arrowShoot {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/arrow.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    arrowShootPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    if (arrowShootPlayer != nil) {
        [arrowShootPlayer play];
    }
}
```

The reason I was allocating memory to the `arrowShootPlayer` every time is because the user can tap the screen rapidly, and I want the sounds to overlap. Otherwise, the sound only plays once the previous one has finished playing.

Anyway, I am getting this error:

```
<com.apple.main-thread> shm_open failed: "AppleAudioQueue.36.5755" (23) flags=0x2 errno=24
```

Once I get this error, the sounds stop being played. Everything else is fine, just the arrow sounds stop playing.

Is there a better way of playing 'overlapping' sounds like this on the iPhone, or is there a way around this error??

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you need close (or reuse) the file manually after it stops playing?

Comment: Another guy not knowing about `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and uses the erroneous and superfluous formatting approach instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is the same audio always, use the playing from memory buffer instead of opening the files. Declare some local buffer:

```
NSData* data;
```

then in your method:

```
if(!data) {
   data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&err];
}
arrowShootPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
if (arrowShootPlayer) {
    [arrowShootPlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Nevertheless you are leaking memory here. You have to make sure to release the AVAudioPlayers somewhere. The easiest way would be to use ARC ;)

Comment: I always use ARC, so if somebody doesn't I let him handle that. :)

Comment: i am having the requirement which will refresh the data from Api at 0.000011sec i have set on timer. so i got this error (Too meany open files) now what can i do ?

Comment: @iosdeveloper , implement a queue. With this refresh rate you won't have time to finish the thread, so its being overlapped and blocking the file closure.

Comment: can you please give me example ?

Comment: @iosdeveloper: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html , for example. This is a standard mechanism for async tasks,